# Some vertices in my mesh seem infinitely far away

Tags: mesh, coordinates

[image: when i open downloaded blender file]

1. Some vertices in the mesh go outside of the viewport. Even when I zoom the view out I cannot find the position of thr vertices. It seems to be infinite.
2. Sometimes a few vertices of the mesh move to the world origin and I'm not able to adjust it.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug, are you using a stable Blender?

Comment: yes .blender 2.82 . problem raise when i open a downloaded blender file.

Comment: Have you tried appending the object from the file into a new file?

Comment: thanks for idea. i export that object as obj file .then i import in new file ,it result the same.but this time i removed all the materials of the object after import . now it work fine without the material .now i assign new material. it works now. so i think the problem is in the materials.but this problem is happening for all the downloaded blender file.

Comment: Really, strange. Perhaps those file are created with the unstable 2.83. Could you upload your file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and post the link to an edit in your question? Then others can check it out. You could remove everything but the problematic vertices/faces/materials before uploading to keep it small.

Comment: no some files are created in 2.7 version.the blender file which i download is from online  has copyright issue.